How to get around Oracle driver error when setting up a jdbc source application for Spring Cloud Dataflow?
I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Dataflow to set up an ETL pipeline with Oracle as the source, a custom application as the processor/transformer, and MySQL as the sink.
Oracle is also used as the database where the Spring Cloud Dataflow Server runs. In order to get that to work with Oracle, I had to make the following changes to pom.xml in spring-cloud-dataflow-server:
diff --git a/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/pom.xml b/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/pom.xml
index da2bc2c72..710ca1287 100644
--- a/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/pom.xml
+++ b/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/pom.xml
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
-               <oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>21.9.0.0</oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>
+               <oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>19.3.0.0</oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>
                <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
                <maven-source-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-source-plugin.version>
                <checkstyle.config.location>../src/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
@@ -171,10 +171,9 @@
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
-                       <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
+                       <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        <version>${oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version}</version>
-                       <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>

That is working fine to allow the Spring Cloud Dataflow web interface to function and have Oracle as its back end.
The problem I am still having with Oracle is that I cannot get it to work as a JDBC source for my stream definition. As I was digging into this, I was pointed toward making a similar update in the pom.xml configuration for Spring Cloud Skipper, as outlined in the documentation.
diff --git a/spring-cloud-skipper/spring-cloud-skipper/pom.xml b/spring-cloud-skipper/spring-cloud-skipper/pom.xml
index 35c68437c..fb6d3f3f0 100644
--- a/spring-cloud-skipper/spring-cloud-skipper/pom.xml
+++ b/spring-cloud-skipper/spring-cloud-skipper/pom.xml
@@ -13,6 +13,7 @@
        </parent>
        <properties>
                <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
+               <oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>19.3.0.0</oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
@@ -75,6 +76,16 @@
                        <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
+               <dependency>
+                       <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
+                       <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
+                       <version>${oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version}</version>
+               </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
                <plugins>

When I deploy my stream, the transformer and the JDBC sink (MySQL) deploy successfully, but I get this error in the standard output for the JDBC source (Oracle):
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I've downloaded the Oracle driver locally and imported it into my local Maven repository and rebuilt Spring Cloud Skipper, all to no avail.
Here is an abbreviated version of my stream definition:
my-stream=oracle: jdbc --max-messages-per-poll=1000 --fixed-delay=30s --password=xxxxxxxx --driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --username=my_user --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-oracle-db.com:1521/my_service_name --update="UPDATE /* ... */" --query="SELECT /* ... */" | my-transform-app | mysql: jdbc --password="xxxxxxxx" --driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --username=my_user --url="jdbc:mysql://my-mysql-db.com:3306/my_database" --table-name=my_table

Anybody know what I might be missing for setting up a JDBC source to use Oracle without getting a driver error?

A few things to note from above pom.xml file.

Why two versions of ojdbc8 jars are being loaded/referred. Make sure to use always one version of the JDBC jar. 
<oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>21.9.0.0</oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version> 
<oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>19.3.0.0</oracle-driver-ojdbc8.version>

In maven dependency I see the group id as "com.oracle.jdbc" but it should be "com.oracle.database.jdbc"


